# How can I Blur the app background in WinUI 3?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winui-3

Is there any way to get a blurred app background in WinUI 3 with Windows 11 SDK? I've seen it become quite popular lately, and one of the apps that I've actually used a lot has it (Fluent Terminal). I'm basically trying to replicate that effect. It doesn't need to be an exact copy, just something working that looks good. Here's an image for reference:

[image: Image reference]

Comment: That's not blur exactly. That's Mica. Unfortunately, Mica and Acrylic materials are both not supported CURRENTLY in WinUI 3.

Comment: Thanks! Heard it will be getting support in SDK version 1.1, but thought there is a way before it releases

Comment: Yes you heard it right, but unfortunately you'll have to wait for Windows App SDK version 1.1.